# Keep standalone bash script app open after run of script

Tags: macos, bash, script, automation

I have a bash script that I have turned into a standalone macOS app (i.e. I created a folder `Script.app` which contains subfolders `Contents` and `MacOS` and in the folder MacOS resides my bash script). If I open the app the bash script runs and after the successful run, the app closes immediately.

I would like the app to remain open and run another bash script upon quitting the app. Or, if this cannot be done, perform some Finder action upon quitting (more precisely unmounting a Volume).

Comment: Just create a second app to unmount the volume again. Or use AppleScript (but then you also have to handle situations where a user unmounts by ejecting the drive in Finder)

Comment: Sure, I could create a second app, but that's not the functionality I would like to achieve. You write _Or use apple script_. To do what exactly?

Comment: To implement the functionality you want :-)

Comment: I don't know how to use AppleScript to keep the app open after the bash script has exited (and it looks to me like there is no such functionality in Apple Script). My guess would be that I rather have to modify the app itself.

Comment: You would need to write the whole thing in AppleScript.

Comment: Why not just unmount the volume at the end of the original bash script?

Comment: Ok, so AppleScript allows me to create a script which I can export as a standalone app that does execute the bash script and stay open. Thanks a lot so far @nohillside! What I don't know yet is how I can define an action that is executed when I quit the so created app.

Comment: You'll need to add a `quit` _handler_, have a look at [idle and quit Handlers for Stay-Open Applications](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH206-SW7).

Comment: Great, this works! Many thanks. I'll formulate the comments as an answer, as it might be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gathering what's above in the comments, here's what works: Use Script Editor to write a script containing

```
do shell script "complete_path_to_start_script"
on quit
    do shell script "complete_path_to_quit_script"
    continue quit
end quit
```

Use Script Editor to export the script as a standalone app which remains open after the start script has terminated. This option can be selected in a checkbox.